# How to create unfilled circles (style) for point layers?

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer and want to visualize it with unfilled circles.

It is only possible to change the colors and size of the symbology layer (single mark).

But I would like to change the filled color of the circle to transparent and the thickness of the border. How can I do that in QGIS?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: related bug/feature request: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3458

Comment: thank's a lot for the answer. So I will use the old style which makes it possible to create unfilled circles :)

Answer (score 3):

This is now easy to do in QGIS 2.8.1. Click on the Simple marker option, then set the fill colour to be transparent and adjust the border/outline style to your liking.

[image]